# Chisel memory write mask

Tags: chisel

I am trying to use a write mask for a Mem in chisel 3 like given below.

```
chipMem.write(data_idx, wdata, wmask)
```

I am generating wmask (the write mask) as follows,

```
val wmask = write_mask.toBools
```

since write_mask is a UInt and the write function requires a Bool Sequence for the write mask argument. However, this gives the following error.

```
Cannot prove that chisel3.core.UInt <:< chisel3.core.Vec[_].
[error]              chipMem.write(data_idx, wdata, wmask)
[error]                           ^
[error] one error found
```

I really don't understand what the error message says. Is it a problem with the way I create wmask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that it cannot prove that a Chisel UInt is a subtype of Chisel Vec (because it isn't).

Taking a look at the [documentation for Mem.write](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/index.html#chisel3.core.Mem@write(idx:chisel3.core.UInt,data:T,mask:Seq[chisel3.core.Bool])(implicitevidence:%3C:%3C[T,chisel3.core.Vec[_]]):Unit), it notes that "this is only allowed if the memory's element data type is a Vec." This could probably be phrased a little better, but basically Chisel does not assume anything about how the write mask corresponds to the data. If you want to use write masks, the datatype of your Mem *must* be a Vec. Also note that the write mask Vec must have the same number of entries as the datatype Vec.

Answer (score 1):

mask work only when memory Datatype is vector.
you can directly write instruction if memory is not Vector
example:

```
val memory = Mem (32 , UInt (32. W ) )
memory . write ( io . addr , io . data_in)
```